# netbeans gradle, deploy to Wildfly

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, wildfly

quite a simple question, but i cannot find a solution:

I imported a gradle Project into netbeans from eclipse, which worked seamlessly, even though i had to fight eclipse itself to barely be able to build it there.

The sole Problem left, keeping me from moving on to netbeans is, i want to be able to deploy the resulting .ear to a wildfly-applicationserver and be able to debug the application.

As netbeans does see the project as a gradle project, it does not offer me the options in the contextmenus to deploy to the configured wildfly, that i can already run and stop from netbeans.

In eclipse i could deploy the ear to a local wildfly in debug-mode and attach the sources off all subprojects (ejb.jar, ...) for eclipse to find while debugging.

How can i configure netbeans to do this?

Comment: The wildfly netbeans plugin can do this if the graddle plugin tells netbeans that this is a Java EE application. From my point of view this is a netbeans graddle issue.

Comment: how would gradle tell netbeans about this?

Comment: Something in the project metadata generated by the graddle plugin when it loads the project. Can't help you there as i don't know much about this plugin nor where is its code.

Comment: I have a series of gradle subprojects that are all of different types, they're listed as gradle projects under the subprojects node of the parent project, however when I double click to open them they're opened as the correct type.  This is done by having a prepared nbproject/project.xml that specifies the type the project should be opened as, in your case that's <data xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2ee-earproject/2">.  I have a gradle task 'nbproject' in the allprojects section of the parent gradle build that sets all subprojects according to the project.xml stored in src/test/resources